# Merge Android Studio activities

Tags: java, android, ioio

I am having a problem with merging two activities in Android Studio. I am new to coding and I know this should be relatively simple but I am slowly learning, so bear with me.

Basically my starting activity was a sample app that came with the IOIO development board. I have modified this to work for my application. I also have a MAX31855 thermocouple amplifier that I have found code for and it is working perfect, the only problem is that all of the code is in a separate activity from my sample app activity. So both will not run at the same time on my simple one screen app. So now I am trying to merge the thermocouple amplifier code into the sample app code. How should I start going about this? I have attached the code for both activities below.

The code for the sample app:

```
package ioio.examples.simple;

import ioio.lib.api.AnalogInput;
import ioio.lib.api.DigitalOutput;
import ioio.lib.api.IOIO;
import ioio.lib.api.exception.ConnectionLostException;
import ioio.lib.util.BaseIOIOLooper;
import ioio.lib.util.IOIOLooper;
import ioio.lib.util.android.IOIOActivity;
import ioio.lib.api.SpiMaster;
import ioio.lib.api.SpiMaster.Rate;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class IOIOSimpleApp extends IOIOActivity {

private TextView boost;
private TextView fuelpressure;
private TextView ioioStatusText;
private TextView internalText;
private TextView thermocoupleText;
private TextView faultsText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    boost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boost);
    fuelpressure = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fuelpressure);
    ioioStatusText   = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ioio_status);
    internalText     = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.internal);
    thermocoupleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.thermocouple);
    faultsText       = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.faults);
    enableUi(false);
}

class Looper extends BaseIOIOLooper {
    private AnalogInput boost, fuelpressure;

    @Override
    public void setup() throws ConnectionLostException {
        boost = ioio_.openAnalogInput(45);
        fuelpressure = ioio_.openAnalogInput(42);
        enableUi(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void loop() throws ConnectionLostException, InterruptedException {
        setNumber1(38.314 * ((boost.getVoltage() - 0.27)));
        setNumber2(38.314 * ((fuelpressure.getVoltage() - 0.27)));
        Thread.sleep(200);
    }

    @Override
    public void disconnected() {
        enableUi(false);
    }
}

@Override
protected IOIOLooper createIOIOLooper() {
    return new Looper();
}
private void enableUi(final boolean enable) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //seekBar_.setEnabled(enable);
            //toggleButton_.setEnabled(enable);
        }
    });
}

private void setNumber1(double f) {
    final String str = String.format("%.0f", f);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boost.setText(str);
        }
    });
}

private void setNumber2(double f) {
    final String str = String.format("%.0f", f);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            fuelpressure.setText(str);
        }
    });
}
}
```

And the code for the thermocouple amplifier:

```
package ioio.examples.simple;

import ioio.lib.api.SpiMaster;
import ioio.lib.api.SpiMaster.Rate;
import ioio.lib.api.exception.ConnectionLostException;
import ioio.lib.util.BaseIOIOLooper;
import ioio.lib.util.IOIOLooper;
import ioio.lib.util.android.IOIOActivity;
import ioio.lib.api.AnalogInput;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends IOIOActivity {

protected static final float FAULT_DISPLAY_DURATION = 10; // seconds

private TextView ioioStatusText;
private TextView internalText;
private TextView thermocoupleText;
private TextView faultsText;
private TextView boost;
private TextView fuelpressure;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ioioStatusText   = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ioio_status);
    internalText     = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.internal);
    thermocoupleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.thermocouple);
    faultsText       = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.faults);
    boost            = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boost);
    fuelpressure     = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fuelpressure);
}

@Override
protected IOIOLooper createIOIOLooper() {
    int sdoPin = 1; // DO
    int sdaPin = 29; // we do not use this pin but the IOIOLib requires we specify it, so we pick an unused pin
    int sclPin = 2; // CLK
    int csPin  = 3; // CS
    Rate rate = SpiMaster.Rate.RATE_31K;
    final MAX31855 max31855 = new MAX31855(sdoPin, sdaPin, sclPin, csPin, rate);
    max31855.setListener(new MAX31855.MAX31855Listener() {
        private long faultTime;

        @Override
        public void onData(float internal, float thermocouple) {
            updateTextView(internalText, "Internal = " + internal + " C");
            updateTextView(thermocoupleText, thermocouple + " C");

            float secondsSinceFault = (System.nanoTime() - faultTime) / 1000000000.0f;
            if (secondsSinceFault > FAULT_DISPLAY_DURATION) {
                updateTextView(faultsText, "Faults = ");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFault(byte f) {
            List<String> faults = new ArrayList<String>();

            if ((f & MAX31855.FAULT_OPEN_CIRCUIT_BIT) == MAX31855.FAULT_OPEN_CIRCUIT_BIT)
                faults.add("Open Circuit");
            if ((f & MAX31855.FAULT_SHORT_TO_GND_BIT) == MAX31855.FAULT_SHORT_TO_GND_BIT)
                faults.add("Short To GND");
            if ((f & MAX31855.FAULT_SHORT_TO_VCC_BIT) == MAX31855.FAULT_SHORT_TO_VCC_BIT)
                faults.add("Short To VCC");

            boolean first = true;
            String text = "Faults = ";
            for (String fault : faults) {
                if (!first)
                    text += ", ";
                text += fault;
            }
            if (faults.size() > 0) {
                faultTime = System.nanoTime();
            }

            updateTextView(faultsText, text);
        }
    });
    return new DeviceLooper(max31855);
}

private void updateTextView(final TextView textView, final String text) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView.setText(text);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * This is the thread on which all the IOIO activity happens. It will be run
 * every time the application is resumed and aborted when it is paused. The
 * method setup() will be called right after a connection with the IOIO has
 * been established (which might happen several times!). Then, loop() will
 * be called repetitively until the IOIO gets disconnected.
 */
class DeviceLooper extends BaseIOIOLooper {

    private IOIOLooper device;

    public DeviceLooper(IOIOLooper device) {
        this.device = device;
    }

    @Override
    public void setup() throws ConnectionLostException, InterruptedException {
        device.setup(ioio_);
        updateTextView(ioioStatusText, "IOIO Connected");
    }

    @Override
    public void loop() throws ConnectionLostException, InterruptedException {
        device.loop();
    }

    @Override
    public void disconnected() {
        device.disconnected();
        updateTextView(ioioStatusText, "IOIO Disconnected");
    }

    @Override
    public void incompatible() {
        updateTextView(ioioStatusText, "IOIO Incompatible");
    }

}

}
```

I hope this makes sense and I have provided enough information. There is another separate activity for the MAX31855, but I assume this can be left untouched. Again, I am slowly learning how java and android studio works, I just can't seem to figure out how to merge these two activities without having a bunch of errors in the code. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider three things.

1) main.xml Layout file in res->layout

2) AndroidManifest.xml in manifest folder

3) Single activity which include all codes.

All components should be initialized from a same activity (in your case MainActivity or IOIOSimpleApp).

Also remember to include all components (what you have initialized from activity) to the main.xml layout.

And try this

```
public class IOIOSimpleApp extends IOIOActivity {

protected static final float FAULT_DISPLAY_DURATION = 10; // seconds

private TextView boost;
private TextView fuelpressure;
private TextView ioioStatusText;
private TextView internalText;
private TextView thermocoupleText;
private TextView faultsText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    boost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boost);
    fuelpressure = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fuelpressure);
    ioioStatusText   = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ioio_status);
    internalText     = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.internal);
    thermocoupleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.thermocouple);
    faultsText       = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.faults);


    //components in main activity
    ioioStatusText   = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ioio_status);
    internalText     = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.internal);
    thermocoupleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.thermocouple);
    faultsText       = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.faults);
    boost            = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boost);
    fuelpressure     = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fuelpressure);

    enableUi(false);
}

class Looper extends BaseIOIOLooper {
    private AnalogInput boost, fuelpressure;

    @Override
    public void setup() throws ConnectionLostException {
        boost = ioio_.openAnalogInput(45);
        fuelpressure = ioio_.openAnalogInput(42);
        enableUi(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void loop() throws ConnectionLostException, InterruptedException {
        setNumber1(38.314 * ((boost.getVoltage() - 0.27)));
        setNumber2(38.314 * ((fuelpressure.getVoltage() - 0.27)));
        Thread.sleep(200);
    }

    @Override
    public void disconnected() {
        enableUi(false);
    }
}

@Override
protected IOIOLooper createIOIOLooper() {
    int sdoPin = 1; // DO
    int sdaPin = 29; // we do not use this pin but the IOIOLib requires we specify it, so we pick an unused pin
    int sclPin = 2; // CLK
    int csPin  = 3; // CS
    SpiMaster.Rate rate = SpiMaster.Rate.RATE_31K;
    final MAX31855 max31855 = new MAX31855(sdoPin, sdaPin, sclPin, csPin, rate);
    max31855.setListener(new MAX31855.MAX31855Listener() {
        private long faultTime;

        @Override
        public void onData(float internal, float thermocouple) {
            updateTextView(internalText, "Internal = " + internal + " C");
            updateTextView(thermocoupleText, thermocouple + " C");

            float secondsSinceFault = (System.nanoTime() - faultTime) / 1000000000.0f;
            if (secondsSinceFault > FAULT_DISPLAY_DURATION) {
                updateTextView(faultsText, "Faults = ");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFault(byte f) {
            List<String> faults = new ArrayList<String>();

            if ((f & MAX31855.FAULT_OPEN_CIRCUIT_BIT) == MAX31855.FAULT_OPEN_CIRCUIT_BIT)
                faults.add("Open Circuit");
            if ((f & MAX31855.FAULT_SHORT_TO_GND_BIT) == MAX31855.FAULT_SHORT_TO_GND_BIT)
                faults.add("Short To GND");
            if ((f & MAX31855.FAULT_SHORT_TO_VCC_BIT) == MAX31855.FAULT_SHORT_TO_VCC_BIT)
                faults.add("Short To VCC");

            boolean first = true;
            String text = "Faults = ";
            for (String fault : faults) {
                if (!first)
                    text += ", ";
                text += fault;
            }
            if (faults.size() > 0) {
                faultTime = System.nanoTime();
            }

            updateTextView(faultsText, text);
        }
    });
    return new IOIOSimpleApp.DeviceLooper(max31855);
}
private void enableUi(final boolean enable) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //seekBar_.setEnabled(enable);
            //toggleButton_.setEnabled(enable);
        }
    });
}

private void setNumber1(double f) {
    final String str = String.format("%.0f", f);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boost.setText(str);
        }
    });
}

private void setNumber2(double f) {
    final String str = String.format("%.0f", f);
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            fuelpressure.setText(str);
        }
    });
}
private void updateTextView(final TextView textView, final String text) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView.setText(text);
        }
    });
}


/**
 * This is the thread on which all the IOIO activity happens. It will be run
 * every time the application is resumed and aborted when it is paused. The
 * method setup() will be called right after a connection with the IOIO has
 * been established (which might happen several times!). Then, loop() will
 * be called repetitively until the IOIO gets disconnected.
 */
class DeviceLooper extends BaseIOIOLooper {

    private IOIOLooper device;

    public DeviceLooper(IOIOLooper device) {
        this.device = device;
    }

    @Override
    public void setup() throws ConnectionLostException, InterruptedException {
        device.setup(ioio_);
        updateTextView(ioioStatusText, "IOIO Connected");
    }

    @Override
    public void loop() throws ConnectionLostException, InterruptedException {
        device.loop();
    }

    @Override
    public void disconnected() {
        device.disconnected();
        updateTextView(ioioStatusText, "IOIO Disconnected");
    }

    @Override
    public void incompatible() {
        updateTextView(ioioStatusText, "IOIO Incompatible");
    }

} }
```

Hope this is work :)

Comment: Hi Sasadara, I have merged the code into one activity like you have above and it seems to be working as intended except that the boost and fuelpresure components do not seems to be updating now. I think it may be a problem with the first looper class as it says "class 'Looper' is never used". I don't have this problem before the code is merged into the single activity. Again, sorry this may seem like a simple question but I am still learning, Thanks

Comment: No problem :) mark it as answered and vote it, if it is okay :)